# Set the Dygraph-Combined.js script as environment variable ? to avoid copying

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have html files in a directory which contains the plot for different simulation result. When I open the html files the graphs are visible in the browser only when the dygraph-combined.js file is present in that directory. Otherwise the graphs are not shown in the browser. So every time I create a html file in a new directory I have to the copy the dygraph-combined.js and put it in the directory to view the graph. Is there any option like setting the environment variable of dygraph.js file so that every time I need not to copy the javascript to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

**this `../`, return one folder**

directory for file JS:

```
one/js/dygraph-combined.js
```

===========================================================

sheet HTML:

```
one/other/here/my.html
```

how acces to js =>

```
...
<script src="../../js/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
...
```

==========================================================

another sheet HTML:

```
one/other/another/another.html
```

how acces to js =>

```
...
<script src="../../js/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
...
```